# Assertion for specific HTTP code in Gatling

Tags: gatling

Is there a way to specify an assertion for a specific HTTP status code, something that would let the job fail if the HTTP status code is e.g 500? According to [Gatlings documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC2/general/assertions.html) we can only differentiate between 'failedRequests' and 'successfulRequests'. But I'd need something in the line of:

```
assertions(global.requestHttpStatus(500).count(0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we don't currently support such assertion.